# How to can I append variable values to a dynamically created html elements in jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I am dynamically creating a html link and I want to set a onclick event with a parameter. Parameters is variable.

```
return '<a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete-btn ml-2" onclick="deleteMeeting('+data[1]+')" >Delete</a>'
```

I am getting an error,

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.
```

Currently it render like this,

```
<a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete-btn ml-2" onclick="deleteMeeting(Junior Technical Author)">Delete</a>
```

Comment: Could you give an example of what it would look like when generated with some data ?

Comment: @Nicolas I added it to the question, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are outputing a string directly into a function call without using `'`. You need to add escaped `'` and place your `data[1]` inside them.

```
return '<a role="button" href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm delete-btn ml-2" onclick="deleteMeeting(\''+data[1]+'\')" >Delete</a>'
```

This way, you will paste your `data[1]` inside a string.